# Laravel 5.2: passing session in a where clause

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and trying to pass an existing session in a where clause:

The session called **currentOrderReference** works as expected and its value is:
31GENERND2342
If I try to get the customer_id using following query, the query does not return any customer_id:

```
$ref = session()->get('currentOrderReference');
Order_reference::select('customer_id')->where('reference',$ref)->first();
```

But if I replace the var **$ref** with its value like this, then it works

```
Order_reference::select('customer_id')->where('reference','31GENERND2342')->first();
```

What I am doing wrong in the first query?

Comment: You can use `$ref = session('currentOrderReference');`, see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

Comment: Don't you think that if `$ref` is empty - then you don't store value in a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please check your session value before putting in query.

After that, try the following syntax for where:

```
->where('reference', '=', $ref)
```